# стандартная функция time() никогда не будет вызвана. Почему?

Tags: php

стандартная функция time() никогда не будет вызвана. Почему?

Следует заметить, что вычисление логических выражений, содержащих такие опера-
ции, идет всегда слева направо, при этом если результат уже очевиден (например, false
&& что-то всегда дает false ), то вычисления обрываются, даже если в выражении при-
сутствуют вызовы функций. Например, в операторе
$logic = 0 && (time() > 100);
стандартная функция time() никогда не будет вызвана.

Comment: ну так в статье и написано... `$logic = 0 && (time() > 100)` первое выражение ложное, значит 2 можно уже не проверять, т.к. всё выражение уже ложно. Вы же сами скопировали это правило.

Comment: где пхп иложное

Comment: В тексте вашего вопроса уже дан ответ на него.

Comment: @HakuKimura мне кажется тут может быть непонятно почему `$logic = 0` ложно) это единственная проблема которую я вижу...

Comment: так ноль - это ложь?

Comment: @sergev ну да. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: Еще один. Котерова тоже читаете?

Comment: Не, это _не совсем_ тролль. Он читает [PHP.SU](http://www.php.su/learnphp/operators/?logical), но, видимо, не подозревает о существовании официальной документации на русском языке, которую тоже стоит читать. И тут нет ключевой фразы `Объясните до мельчайших подробностей и приведите примеры`... 8)

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном выражении `$logic = 0 && (time() > 100);` оператор присвоения имеет наименьший приоритет и будет выполнен последним. Порядок обработки будет такой:

1. Литерал `0` типа integer.
2. Оператор `&&` (он же `and`, логическое "И") - следовательно int(0) будет приводиться к типу `boolean`. Значением `(bool) 0` будет `false`.
3. Значение оператора "логическое И" будет истинным тогда и только тогда, когда оба его аргумента - истинны. У нас же первый аргумент имеет значение `false`. Результат оператора **очевиден** - это `false`.
4. В соответствии с процитированным Вами правилом

> Следует заметить, что вычисление логических выражений, содержащих такие операции, идет всегда слева направо, при этом **если результат уже очевиден (например, false && что-то всегда дает false ), то вычисления обрываются**, даже если в выражении присутствуют вызовы функций

значение второго аргумента оператора `&&` вычисляться **не будет**. Соответственно вызываться функция `time()` тоже **не будет**.

Для получения более подробной информации можете ознакомиться со следующими разделами RTFM:

- [Выражения](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.expressions.php).
- [Булев тип](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).
- [Приоритет оператора](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.precedence.php).